# arc tangent to two lines and through a point

Tags: trigonometry

How can I calculate the radius of a curve that is tangential to two intersecting lines and also passes through a point that is not on either of the lines?

Comment: What data are known?

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

Point $P$ is inside one of the angles formed by the two lines. The center $C$ of the circle belongs to the bisector of that angle. The distance from $C$ to either side of the angle must be  equal to $CP$: that allows you to write an equation and find the position of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything in the $(x,y)$ plane. Assume the lines intersect at the origin $(0,0)$ and that one of the lines is the $x$-axis. Say the center of the circle has coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$ and lives in the first quadrant. Since the circle is tangent to the $x$-axis, the radius of the circle is $r=y_0$.

The center of the circle will lie on the bisector of the lines; if the angle between the lines is $\theta$, then the bisector has equation $y=cx$ where $c=\tan(\theta/2)$. Therefore $y_0=cx_0$.

Suppose the circle passes through the point $(a,b)$. The the distance from the circle center to this point equals the radius of the circle. This gives the equation:
$$(x_0-a)^2 + (y_0-b)^2 = r^2.$$
Substitute $r=y_0=cx_0$ to obtain a quadratic equation for $r$:
$$(\frac rc-a)^2 + (r-b)^2=r^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall the radius of a circle is perpendicular to the tangent line at the point of tangency. Given that your question provides no measurements, I assume you are to use this fact to construct two perpendiculars at the points where the lines meet the circle. Where the two perpendiculars meet is the center of your circle, and then you will be able to determine the length of the radius.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Let given fixed point be P, variable center of circle C, length of perpendicular along normal to first curve p1, for second curve, p2. Then

$$ PC = p1 \, ; PC = p2$$

For tangency take circle K equation as
$$ (x-h)^2 +(y-k)^2 = PC^2$$

and calculate roots of intersection of curve 1 and circle K and set discriminant = 0  for tangentcy condition. So also for curve 2.

This adequate to find $(h,k,PC). $